# Understanding of process_backlog and softnet_data fields in kernel 3.3.8

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand process_backlog() function from linux kernel 3.3.8.

I know that there is a list of incoming skb structs called "input_pkt_queue". This list is a member of softnet_data struct. 
There is also another skb list in softnet_data called "process_queue".

All the incoming skb go to "input_pkt_queue". I wonder what is the purpose of the second list "process_queue".

I'm asking for it because process_backlog() I think should operate on "input_pkt_queue" but it operates on "process_queue".

Is the "process_queue" list some kind of temporary working list, but "input_pkt_queue" is used only for gathering skb to allow other cpu's to still gather skb's into "input_pkt_queue"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes , you are right the packets are queued to the input queue if RPS(Receive Packet Steering is On). The process_backlog which is called from the softirq context does indeed de-queue from the process queue but you may have missed that it actually joins the input queue to the process backlog queue

```
if (qlen)//Basically this is joining the input queue to the process queue
                        skb_queue_splice_tail_init(&sd->input_pkt_queue,                 
                                                   &sd->process_queue);
```

Hence while the loop iterates it will dequeue from the process queue, remember in the first iteration the process queue was empty and from 2nd itereation the process queue has list of skbs that are queued  from the drives in the  interrupt context(!softirq).

Comment: Is there a reason to use two queues?

Answer (score 1):

2 lists are used to reduce the lock contention. Packets are dequeued in batch from input_packet_queue into to process_queue.

Here is the [link](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg127703.html) to this commit.